# How can I stop my program from reading the serial port buffer?

Tags: c, serial-port

I have a working program to read data coming from the terminal. The problem is that when, for example, a data come and stop, my program keep reading from the buffer. How can I stop it from reading things that already came through the port?

Here is my code, which can also be [found at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/66S5hSAb)

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>


int open_port(void);

int main()
{
    char dato[1];
    int fd = 0;
    fd = open_port();
    while(1)
    {
        read(fd,dato,1);
        //~ if(dato == "B")
        //~ return 0;
        printf(dato);
    }
}

int open_port(void)
{
    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */  

    //~ fd = open("/home/tomas/ttySV1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NDELAY);
    //~ fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);

    if (fd == -1)
    { 
        perror("open_port: No se pudo abrir el puerto: ");
    }
    else
    {
        struct termios options;

        /*
         * Get the current options for the port...
         */

        tcgetattr(fd, &options);

        /*
         * Set the baud rates to B9600...
         */

        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);

        /*
         * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
         */

        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

        /*
         * Set the new options for the port...
         */

        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */

        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;

        //~ fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        return (fd);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know when you've read enough data? (ie what are your stopping conditions?)

Comment: The are no stop conditions, I mean, I always scan the port looking for data to come, but I don't know how to clear the buffer to stop reading past data.

Comment: according to [this reference](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html), `read` should block until new content is available on the open pipe.

Comment: Why are you using O_NDELAY? And what do you mean by 'reading past data?'

Comment: It really is better if questions at SO are self-contained rather than referring to external sites for the code under discussion. This is even more important when the external reference is transient.

Comment: I tried to paste the code here, but it was a mess, so I end up in pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O_NDELAY prevents the read from blocking.  You should always check return codes.  Read will return -1 and set errno to EWOULDBLOCK.

So play with return codes and errno to figure out what to do --  example:

```
ssize_t retval=1;
int doit=1;
while(doit)
{
 while( retval==1)
 {
    retval=read(fd, &ch, 1);
 }
 if(retval == -1)
 {
  if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
  {
      sleep 1;    
  }
  else
     doit=0;
}
```

Comment: It would be more to the point to use blocking mode rather than sleeping for an arbitrary interval, which is either too long if data arrives or too short if data doesn't arrive.

Comment: I wasn't reading the return of `read()` it's all right now. Thanks!